Is there a way to conditionally format a range of cells based on ONE cell in that range, and then use that formatting on a 'range of ranges'?
Firstly, I'm really sorry if this has already been answered but I have tried to find a similar case.
I have a range, A1:B3, which I will turn into a 'box'. All the cells in the range do various things, but B2 (top right corner) yields a percentage calculated from some SUMIFs that refer to the value in A1. I want the entire box (A1:B3) to colour red/amber/green/red and black based upon the percentage value of B1. To do this I have 4 rules;



Rule
FORMAT
AppliesTo




=$B$1>1
RED/BLACK Pattern
=$A$1:$B$3


=$B$1>=0.8
RED
=$A$1:$B$3


=$B$1>=0.5
AMBER
=$A$1:$B$3


=$B$1>=0
GREEN
=$A$1:$B$3



This works exactly as I want, formatting the entire box. But here comes the problem. I then need a table of these boxes (36 boxes (6x6)). I want each box to conditionally format itself as per the rules above, based on its relative A1, for example box C4:D6 will format based on the percentage in D4.
When I unfix the reference in the rule, it no longer works, as the rule is changing for each cell in the range (which I want it to do but only for each box, not each cell).
So I can create one of these boxes as above, working correctly, and then copy it, with its conditional formatting, to fill the range A1: K18. But I then have 144 rules, and I have to manually change the rule and range for each rule!
I would ideally use the 'colour scale' conditional format but that, so far as I can see, only applies to each cell within a range and won't allow to to format by 'box' at a time.
Here's an image of my boxes after copy and pasting the format. Currently (because it's copied and pasted), each box is formatting red based on the top left percentage for A1 (100%). But every box containing 0% should be green.
So, thank you so much for reading this far. Can excel do this by itself? I will need to do this a few times over and doing it manually would be a catastrophic time hog.
Current table of boxes

I've read this three times and finally come to the conclusion that whenever you say B2 in the text, you actually mean B1. Later on, when you say D4, you actually mean D4. Does this sound right? I'm still not sure why the cells in the screenshot are all coming out red rather than green though.

Yes, my bad. B1 is the percentage value for A1:B3. D4 is correct, the percentage value for C4:D6. Will edit.

The screenshot is just after I've copied a working box to make 6x6 of them. They all have their own rules but reference the original fixed references. So that's why they are currently red. I need to fix the code/method to make it work, OR edit each of the 144 (141 as the first four are the source) times. That's the part I really really want to avoid. Using relative references doesn't work as it breaks the original formatting

I've just tried it with the 'green' rule so far. You have to do some arithmetic with the row and column numbers so that it references the top left and top right cells in each box:
=INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+2)/INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+1)=0

and apply that to the whole range (just popping out so will see if it works for you when I get back).


This is the whole thing but I've just used grey for the Red and Black rule. You could alternate colours within a block but setting black as a background colour isn't usually advisable because you can't read the value in the cell unless you change the font colour as well.
The formulas are:
=INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+2)/INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+1)>=0

=INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+2)/INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+1)>=0.5

=INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+2)/INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+1)>=0.8

=INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+2)/INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+1)>=1

(actually the last one should be >1 to match your question)

Try this to get an alternating colour effect:
=(INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+2)/INDEX($A$1:$F$6,QUOTIENT(ROW()-1,3)*3+1,QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-1,2)*2+1)>=1)*ISODD(ROW()+COLUMN())


Thanks for your time! I've had to finish for now too. I'll explore this first thing Monday and if it works you'll have saved me so much time! Thanks
